# Redundancy of displaying in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny, tabpanel

I am learning how to build shiny app and I have some problems with my code and I have no idea how to solve it.

Here is my `ui.R` file:

```
cv_global <- read.csv("coronavirus_global.csv")
bootstrapPage(
  tags$head(includeHTML("gtag.html")),
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "VISUALISATION LE COVID-19", id="nav",

             tabPanel("GLOBAL",
                       sidebarPanel(

                           span(tags$i(h6("Permet de visualiser la revolution du Covid-19 dans le monde dans la période de 4 mois")), style="color:#045a8d"),

                           selectInput("condition","Choisir observation:",
                                       choices = c("Cas","Nouveaux cas","Décès","Nouveaux décès")),

                           selectInput("display","Type de visualisation: ",
                                       choices = c("Histogramme","Camembert"))
                                   )   

                        ),

             tabPanel("COVID-19 mapper",
                      div(class="outer",
                          tags$head(includeCSS("styles.css")),
                          leafletOutput("mymap", width="100%", height="100%"),
                      )

             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("image")
             )
  )

  )
```

Here is my `server.R` file:

```
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
function(input, output) {


  ConditionInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$condition,
           "Cas" = cases,
           "Niveau Cas" = newcases,
           "Décès" = death,
           "Nouveaux décès" = new_death)
  })

  new_cv_global <- cv_global %>%
    group_by(global_level, Month = format(as.Date(date), "%B")) %>%
    summarise(case_each_month = sum(cases, na.rm = TRUE))



  output$image <- renderPlot({
    if(input$display == "Histogramme") {

      new_cv_global %>%
        mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = month.name)) %>%
        arrange(Month) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = case_each_month )) +
        geom_col()
    }
  })   
}
```

The problem is that I can display the histogram plot in the first `tabPanel` but it also appear in the second `tabPanel` which is not my wish. How can I solve this problem?

Anyway, you can access the file like csv, css, html here through the link:
https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/tree/master

Any help for this would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Your `plotOutput` is not within a tab, so it will be below the tabset, appearing as if it is in both (but really being in neither).

Comment: Where should I put it then?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I interpret your statement *"it also appear in the second `tabPanel`"* to mean that you think it should be completely within the first tab panel. If that's the case, then why isn't it *in the first tab*?

Comment: Is it your intent that the side navbar be in only one tabset? I haven't tested that, does that work?

Comment: To answer myself: a `sidebarPanel` can be encapsulated within a single tab.